# Ubuntu 11.04 not booting up

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I try to boot up and get the following text on screen:

```
The PostgreSQL server failed to start. Please check the log output:

Starting Postfix Mail Transport Angen postfix
speech-dispatcher disabled: edit /etc/default/speech-dispatcher
Starting the Winbin daemon winbind
Starting bluetooth
PulseAudio configured for per-user sessions
saved disabled: edit /etc/default/saved
Starting web server apache2
apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using ::1 for Server...

Checking battery state...
```

Then it just holds there and shuts down. How can I get it to boot up? The last thing I remember doing was changing the computer name...

I can access the console in recovery mode, but it's only got read and write permissions so I can't move any of the data on there - I really need to save some databases and move them to a different machine.

Answer (score 0):

I would check battery state because that's where boot up sequence stops. If it is laptop then connect it to power source.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - that's what I thought, but it's plugged in and when I boot up with windows it shows that the power is fine (even without power lead attached).

Comment: Can you boot into recovery mode ?

Comment: Yes that's fine. I can access the console in recovery mode.

Comment: Then I would guess your issue has something to do with what ever you did in your last session. I am no expert in Ubuntu (or Linux) but I think you need to rollback your changes from your last session and see if that helps.

Comment: I need to grab some databases off the computer, but it'll only give me read and write permissions in the console.

Comment: These links might give you some idea, http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man8/fsck.8.html and https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/i386/rescue.html

Comment: Can you not use Live CD to boot and copy whatever data you need to copy ? I am not sure how copying database and restoring on another system works though.

Comment: Ah thanks - that's a good idea. Thanks for your help today.